# Does a polyurethane floor need a very level substrate?

Tags: flooring, polyurethane, new-home

I'm Dutch so I might have some of the technical terms wrong.

My partner and I have been hitting up businesses because we want a PU floor in our newly built apartment, but the information we get seems to vary quite a bit whenever we speak to different sales people/companies. I was wondering if y'all could help us answer some questions:

- Do we need leveling compound? Some companies mention it isn't necessary for a new apartment mentioning that the pre-PU coat will be fine. while others say they would never lay a PU floor without it. Most seem to go for 3 layers, some 5. primer > cast floor > Primer > coating> varnish is what we're currently leaning towards.
- What's up with the "depth" of the floor? We got some saying 2-3mm and others saying 4 to 6. The 4-6 guys are the ones saying we don't need leveling compound. Is thicker better?

And anything else we should watch out for?

Comment: A) I presume "PU" is polyurethane, is that correct? B) asking for brand recommendations is _explicitly_ off-topic. C) We work on a one question per post basis here. Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we're a bit different than general discussion forums.

Comment: Product and brand recommendations are off topic here. Please take the [tour], then revise to ask just one clear question. Provide enough information for us to help. (We have no idea whether you need a leveler because you've said nothing about the substrate.) See the [help] for more information.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "polyurethane floor". I know polyurethane varnish as a surface finish for wood, but that doesn't seem to be what you are asking about...

Comment: Sounds similar in concept to an epoxy floor coating (more common in schools/healthcare/industry, but sometimes seen in homes) but presumably with a polyurethane product rather than an epoxy product. A thicker floor coating will be more tolerant of minor level issues than a thinner floor coating. Better or worse, I can't say.